# ООП в javascript, какое оно?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Я джуниор и пока что имел опыт ООП только в СИподобных языках и по этому у меня возникает резонный вопрос. Что есть ООП и классы в javascript?

Правильно ли будет вот так вот "определять класс"?

```
function Coordinates() {
    this.x = 0.0;
    this.y = 0.0;
    function GetX() {return this.x;}
    function SetX(x) {this.x = x;}
    function GetY() {return this.y;}
    function SetY(y) {this.y = y;}
    return this;
}
```

а затем использовать это как то так

```
var test = Coordinates();
test.SetX(1);
test.GetX();
```

или это в корне неправильно и я вообще дурак и дилетант? Если это неправильно, то как будет правильно?

Comment: нет не правильно, _return this_ нужно убрать, и вызывать _var test = new Coordinates();_

Comment: @Grundy, это единственный недочет?

Comment: В Javascript вовсе нет классов. Вы можете как-то эмулировать их, но это всё равно будет не класс, а его эмуляция. Ваш код, например, пытается эмулировать конструктор.

Comment: @VladD, все зависит от того что вы понимаете под классом ;-)

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, представьте, что вы приходите в магазин купить айфон. А вам вместо него дают Блекберри, и говорят, что ну короче если не поворачивать и наклеить сзади яблочко, то будет практически не отличить от айфона. То же и здесь. Если эмуляцию класса назвать классом, то она будет называться классом.

Comment: Есть же куча статей и учебников. 
Вот учебник на [javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/js). 
Там две темы: ООП в функциональном стиле и ООП в прототипном стиле.

Comment: Ужасное и кошмарное лол )))

Comment: @VladD, ок, можете дать определение класса и пояснить почему в яваскрипте только эмуляция? :)

Comment: @IntFloat, да, я понимаю, что в интернете есть не мало информации об этом, просто меня ооочень смутило создание объектов с методами и свойствами через функцию) Это прям что то новое) Выходящее далеко за рамки для меня на данный момент)

Comment: @user3239600, функция это просто конструктор

Comment: @Grundy: [Тип данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), определяющийся свои интерфейсом (жёстко определённый и контролируемый компилятором набор методов) и своей реализацией (общей для всех экземпляров). Добавить инкапсуляцию, полиморфизм и наследование.

Comment: @VladD и по каким критериям тут не подходят классы в яваскрипте?:)

Comment: @VladD то есть, если язык интерпретируемый у него не может быть классов в принципе? :)

Comment: @VladD, _инкапсуляцию, полиморфизм и наследование._ и чего и этого по вашему не хватает в яваскрипте?

Comment: @Grundy: Нету жёстко контролируемого интерфейса, нету общей для всех экземпляров реализации. Инкапсуляции и наследования тоже нету. Полиморфизм есть.

Comment: @Grundy: Почему же? Вон древние версии Java без JIT-компилятора были вполне себе интерпретируемыми, но никто ж не скажет, что это был не ОО-язык.

Comment: @VladD, как это нет наследования? вполне себе есть.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33223/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Comment: @Grundy: Есть эмуляция наследования, вы хотели сказать? В языке наследования нету.

Comment: @VladD вроде бы в EcmaScript 6 появились классы. Разве нет? Или там тоже эмуляция?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Я не в курсе, Grundy мне указал на документацию в чате, вполне может быть, что в свежей версии появились.

Comment: @VladD,@АлексейШиманский, ну вообще они в итоге разворачиваются в те же прототипы

Comment: Ну, в конечном итоге классы разворачиваются в машинный код. Но это ж не значит, что машинный код содержит классы?

Answer (score 3):

В JS как он есть сейчас нет классов, есть **прототипы**. Ну и подход что прототипы пишутся как **функции**. Как эти прототипы воспринимать - дело каждого отдельного прогера.

Обычно все знают ООП, поэтому держат в голове ООП, а запись через функции и прототипы - типа "синтаксис". Но это не обязательно. Можно считать прототипы основой, они позволяют больше чем ООП. Однако за хитрые выкрутасы вас съедят с потрохами те кто будет читать ваш код :)))

В новом стандарте JS есть нормальнык классы, как в ООП и как все привыкли. Внутри они работают через прототипы, зато внешне всякие классы, методы и т.п., а не каша с прототипами.

Если не нравится синтаксис то есть TypeScript и прочие, они компилятся в JS, в них нормальные классы и прочие крутые штуки.

Answer (score 2):

На JavaScript 'класс' можно определить так

```
var Coordinates = (function() {
    function Coordinates() {
       this.x = 0.0;
    }
    Coordinates.prototype.GetX = function() { return this.x; };
    Coordinates.prototype.SetX = function(x) { this.x = x; };
    return Coordinates;
})();
```

или, если вместо GetX и SetX надо определить свойство X, то так

```
var Coordinates = (function() {
    function Coordinates() {
        this.x = 0.0;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Coordinates.prototype, "X", {
        get: function() { return this.x; },
        set: function(x) { this.x = x; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Coordinates;
})();
```

тоже самое на TypeScript:

```
class Coordinates {
    private x = 0.0;
    get X() { return this.x; }
    set X(x) { this.x = x; }
}
```

Транслировать TypeScript в JavaScript можно онлайн в [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground).

Comment: То, что вы написали — не классы, а их эмуляция средствами языка. Так и ассемблер можно объявить объектно-ориентированным.

Comment: @VladD _"То, что вы написали — не классы"_ -- поэтому 'класс' - в кавычках.

Comment: Окей, уточнение принято.